# Why does fontspec interfere with Ligatures? (In retrospect: How the dutch hyphenate)

Tags: fontspec, context, hyphenation, ligatures

The `tufte` sample text (provided by ConTeXt) contains a `||` sequence which normally gets turned
into an emdash. For some reason the inclusion of `fontspec` disables this.
I've tried to use various options for   `\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=...}`
with no effect. What's going on? (I'm using Tex-live 2015).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[paperwidth=6in,paperheight=6in,textwidth=4in]{geometry} 

\usepackage{fontspec} % commenting this causes || to be interpreted as an emdash

\baselineskip=12pt  

\begin{document}
{
    \input tufte
}
\end{document}
```

**Edit**:

As it turns out, ConTeXt renders that `||` entirely differently, so the original question is actually expressing misunderstanding. `fontspec` and encodings are not the issue.

Comment: That's a ligature that works only with OT1-fontencoding, you would loose it with T1 too.

Comment: Using `||` to produce a long dash is abusing the system.

Comment: That's the contents of `/tex/context/sample/tufte.tex`. I didn't put it there... :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `||` for producing a double em-dash is abusing the system. The fact that `|` produces an em-dash, when the output font encoding is OT1, is purely incidental and should never be relied upon.

The “right” way in TeX/LaTeX for obtaining an em-dash is by typing `---` and this works also with `fontspec`, provided the `Ligatures=TeX` option, that's activated by default, has not been disabled for a particular font.

If a text uses `|` for an em-dash, the text is wrong and should be fixed.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[paperwidth=6in,paperheight=6in,textwidth=4in]{geometry}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{catchfile,etoolbox}

\begin{document}

% emulate editing the faulty file
\CatchFileDef\tufte{tufte}{}
\patchcmd{\tufte}{||}{------}{}{}

\tufte

\end{document}
```

[image]

In any case, a double em-dash is not something I use.

Comment: A font encoding maps each characters to a slot-number in a font file, where glyphs live. How can XeTeX "choose" to use EU1, or any engine "default" to encoding X, when it is a property of the font file? Shouldn't the encoding always be specific to each used font and the user be freeto mix them freely? why is it considered a global thing?

Comment: @JaredKulik The EU1 encoding is basically for mapping *constructs* to glyphs (accents, control sequences producing text and so on). For instance, a document written for “classical LaTeX” could have commands such as `\"u` or `\textemdash`; the purpose of `eu1enc.def` is to map these constructs to the correct glyphs or to provide alternative definitions.

Comment: May be (only may be) it's not intended as a double em-dash. In ConTeXt, `||` means something, and `\input tufte` is commonly used in ConTeXt.

Comment: ConTeXt compiles the double bar into a *single* emdash, so what encoding is *it* using? (no luck searching the manual). Also, OT1 produces one emdash per bar, but there's nothing like that in `ot1enc.def`. Still scratching my head.

Comment: @JaredKulik As far as I can see, `|` is *active* in ConTeXt. If I copy the text, I see two hyphens (probably with some back spacing between them). If I try a single `|`, the compilation hangs.

Comment: @JaredKulik If I try `|||` I get a single bar. I'd tell you to look in the manual, if one existed.

Comment: `|` may be active, but `||` produces a hyphen (not an emdash as I stated).  `core-mis.mkii` contains `\def||{-}` for reasons which are beyond me. Ok, case closed.

Comment: @JaredKulik `\starttext a-b a||b\stoptext` produces sensibly different outputs. I guess that Hans Hagen doesn't like the hyphen and prefers a double one.

Comment: Right again.  So it seems as far back as mkii, `||` was remapped in ConTeXt. But I can't find where that definition happens in mkiv, I've grepped everywhere.

Comment: @JaredKulik From what I see, `|` expands to `\catcodecommand{124}`

Comment: That's what `\tracingmacros=1` says, but I can't find where its defined. Annoying.

Comment: @egreg: _"I'd tell you to look in the manual, if one existed"_. That comment is a bit underhanded. In any case, this behavior is documented in Section 10.8 of the [ConTeXt manual](http://pmrb.free.fr/contextref.pdf).

Comment: @Aditya It would be nice if the manual were available through the standard `texdoc` (it isn't). I have `contextref.pdf` only because I still have TeX Live 2012; it is anything but a user manual. The ConTeXt community should produce a real one.

Comment: @egreg: I agree that it would be nice if the context manuals were included in Texlive. For a history of why it is not included, read [this old thread](http://www.tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2006-January/009650.html) on the tex-live mailing list. On the other hand, the links to the manuals are available on the context wiki.

Answer (score 5):

After a few false starts, it became clear that `||` is the result of a ConTeXt convention, and for reasons more interesting than mere caprice.

From ConTeXt's `lang-mis.mkiv` file:

> One of TEX's strong points in building paragraphs is the way hyphenations are
>   handled. Although for real good hyphenation of non-english languages some
>   extensions to the program are needed, fairly good results can be reached with the
>   standard mechanisms and an additional macro, at least in Dutch.
>
> CONTEXT originates in the wish to typeset educational materials, especially in
>   a technical environment. In production oriented environments, a lot of compound
>   words are used. Because the Dutch language poses no limits on combining words, we
>   often favor putting dashes between those words, because it facilitates reading,
>   at least for those who are not that accustomed to it.
>
> In TEX compound words, separated by a hyphen, are not hyphenated at all.

Aha! True.

[image]

> Inspite of the multiple pass paragraph typesetting this can lead to parts of words
>   sticking into the margin. 
>   [...]
>   The sequence `||` simply leads to two words connected by a hyphen. Because
>   we want to distinguish such a hyphen from the one inserted when TeX hyphenates
>   a word, we use a bit longer one.

Because ConTeXt has deep roots in dutch, a language which often features many-compounded words, a case TeX's hyphenation doesn't handle well.
The solution than, as I understand it, to replace the hyphen with something
visually similar, without triggering TeX's no-hyphenate-compound-words policy.
So in ConTeXt all compound words are joined by `||` rather than by a hyphen.

Defining `||` to do this also takes place in `lang-mis.mkiv`, and uses a `|` (single) as an active character (as @egreg pointed out).

```
\def\compoundhyphen    {\hbox{-\kern-.25ex-}}
\def\defaultdiscretionaryhyphen{\compoundhyphen}
\installdiscretionary | \defaultdiscretionaryhyphen
```

Of course, using that in a sample of english text in a compound-word
which isn't that long is a curious choice, but that's propbably due
to force-of-habit-and-also-being-dutch.

Comment: In ConTeXt MkIV, it is not required to use `||` to get hyphenation of compound words. Instead, you can simply use `\setbreakpoints[compound]` and `compound-words-will-be-hyphenated`.